Prove that $0_Y$ is an iner point of a linear mapping between Banach space.
Question:
Let $X,Y$ two Banach space and $l$ a continuous surjective linear mapping from $X$ to $Y$. Prove that it exists a $r>0$ such that $2r B_Y \subseteq Adh(l(B_X)) $.
With $B_X$ and $B_Y$ the unit sphere of, respectively $X$ and $Y$.
Answer:
So far my idea is to prove that $0_Y$ is an inner point of $Adh(l(B_X))$ and then the following will be easy.
I ve succeeded to prove that $Int(Adh(l(B_X)))$ is not empty. But I am falling in proving the last part: that $0_Y \in Int(Adh(l(B_X)))$ (it is obvious that $0_Y \in l(B_X)$).
I am stuck for a long time on this. Any help will be great.

What is Adh?? you are trying to prove some kind of open mapping theorem.

Thk for your comment. It means the "closure" (in a topological meaning)

@daw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)

I have just had an idea. I hope this is correct.
1- As $Adh(l(B_X))$ is not empty, it means that $ \exists y^* \in Adh(l(B_X)), \exists r^* > 0$ s.t. $ B^*=B(y^*;r^*) \subset Adh(l(B_X))$ or write differently we have that $B^* \subseteq l(B_X) $.
More over by the surjectivity of $l(.) \Rightarrow \exists x^* \in B_X$ s.t. $l(x^*)=y^*$.
Rem: W.l.o.g. $ y^* \neq 0_Y $  if not there is nothing to prove.
2- We continue and we choose $-x^*$ by the property of $l(.) \Rightarrow l(-x^*) = -y^*$. We note too immediately that $-x^* \in B_X$ thus $-y^* \in l(B_X)$
3- Now as $B_X$ is convex so $l(B_X)$ is too convex and $Int(l(B_X))$ is too convex.  Hence the segment $y^* \lambda + (1- \lambda) (- y^*)$ is tottaly in $Int(l(B_X)), \forall \lambda \in [0;1]$. So in particular too for $\lambda = 1/2$ but in such a case we get that $0_Y \in Int(l(B_X))$
Q.E.D.
Is it correct?
